# Real time stats of data sent and received by devices connected to my router

Tags: networking, router, network-traffic

At home I have a configuration like this:

```
                                        +--> XBOX
                                        |
                                        +--> MAC
                Comcast      WiFi N     |
internet <----> Modem <----> Linksys <--+--> PC with OneDrive enabled.
                             E2500      |
                             Router     +--> iPhone 1
                                        |
                                        +--> iPhone 2
                                        |
                                       etc.
```

So, there are many devices. Sometimes I feel the network is too slow, but I don't know if it is Comcast fault or any of my devices is consuming network like a thirsty cow.

So I wonder if there is a router, a modem, an intermediary proxy or something that allows me to see in real time how much data my devices are sending and receiving.

My Linksys stats are so poor. It's a list of the last 10 connections that only contains what local IP address connected to what internet IP address. No amount of data received, no amount of data sent, no host names, no date and time, no more than 10 records.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [tomatousb](http://tomatousb.org) firmware on your router, it looks like the Linksys E2500 is [supported](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140727204148AA6ipGc). This would give you some pretty good [bandwidth monitoring tools](http://www.nextgendigitalhome.com/2127/home-network/scalable-gateway/using-the-tomato-firmware-to-monitor-bandwidth-by-ip-address/):

[image]

---

[dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) is [another possibility](http://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2014/07/01/bandwidth-monitoring-with-dd-wrt/), but i'm not sure what exactly it displays on its "active clients" page:

[image]